# Apache Phusion Passenger on CentOS fails to start because of permission denied on /tmp after updating to4.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, permission-denied

I understand there are a ton of duplicates of this, but non of them have helped, I have updated Passenger from 3.0.19 to 4.0.6, and all the sudden I get a forbidden error,
I looked in the log and the error log says

```
[ 2013-07-05 12:01:51.3604 2639/7fec9151f720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:596 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/xxxx/tmp/passenger.1.0.2634/generation-0/request
[ 2013-07-05 12:01:51.3654 2644/7f29f6ebf7e0 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:303 ]: *** ERROR: Cannot bind Unix socket '/xxxx/tmp/passenger.1.0.2634/generation-0/logging_admin': Permission denied (errno=13)
     in 'void Passenger::MessageServer::startListening()' (MessageServer.h:333)

[Fri Jul 05 12:01:51 2013] [error] *** Passenger could not be initialized because of this error: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger logging agent: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1
[Fri Jul 05 12:01:51 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I understand this is being caused because of passenger not being able to create /xxxx/tmp/passenger.1.0.2634/generation-0/request, but have no idea why

I have tried,

1.setting the user to apache in the conf file.

2.set the tmp folder to the tmp in my rails file, rather than /tmp

3.checked that all files and folders in the rails folder are owned by apache:apache

4.SeLinux was on, have permanently disabled it

Here are my current apache conf settings.

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.6/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.6
   PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/bin/ruby
   PassengerTempDir /xxxx/tmp

   PassengerUserSwitching off
   PassengerDefaultUser apache

   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName xxxxxxx.com
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /xxxx/public

       <Directory /xxxx/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

EDIT

for now I have reverted to the earlier version, and the problems seem to subside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression in 4.0.6. It has been fixed in 4.0.7, just released.

Comment: had a feeling it was a version specific issue, this had to happen on a production server update.